# valor do textbox para outro textbo usando Tabcontrol e Tabpages

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou usando em um form um `TabControl`, com três páginas.

Na `TabPage1` tenho um `TextBox` (vendedor), preciso levar o valor deste TextBox para outro `TextBox` que está na  `TabPage3`.

Como posso fazer isso entre as paginas do TabControl sendo que o form é único?

Segue o `Load()` do form:

```
private void frmComissaoPic_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand carrega = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT SA.A3_NREDUZ FROM SA3010 AS SA WHERE SA.A3_TIPO = 'E'", conexaoDADOADV(true));
    carrega.Connection = conex;
    carrega.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = carrega.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);

        txt_vendedor.DisplayMember = "A3_NREDUZ";
        txt_vendedor.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a retornar por favor verifique como o Administrador do sistema");
    }

    CloseButtonDisabler.DisableCloseButton(this.Handle.ToInt32());

    txt_vendatab3.Text = txt_vendedor.Text;            
    txt_nfe.Text      = "";
    txt_pedido.Text   = "";
    txt_item.Text     = "";
}
```

Comment: Precisa "levar o valor" quando? Enquanto for digitado? Ao clicar num botão? Ao trocar de página? Aliás, o código postado não é útil para a questão.

Comment: Boa tarde...então preciso levar o valor ao trocar de pagina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só usar o evento `Selecting` do `TabControl`

```
public void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    txtDois.Text = txt_vendedor.Text;
    // Onde, txtDois é o TextBox que vai receber este dado
}
```

Você pode inscrever o evento usando o *form designer* ou então no (ou após) o método `InitializeComponents()`

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    tabControl1.Selecting += tabControl1_Selecting;
}
```

Comment: Linq só mais uma duvida, eu consigo dentro deste comando fazer um select e executar uma query também ao mudar de pagina sem precisar de um botão

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Consegue

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Conseguiu resolver o problema da publicação?

Comment: Sim resolvi sim.....obrigado..